# Need general guide on how to build Linux Stream (LiS) under RedHat 6.2

Tags: rhel, compiling, libraries, glibc

## Day 1

I have hit into some error, and the build simply fail, saying that there is some conflict. Thus I believe a .o file cannot be made and then result fatal error during linking, anyone have steps by steps trouble shooting tips ?

I have been successful do it on a clean install of red hat 6, so i suspect someone have update the kernel but didn't update the kernel library. Need some hints on where should i check

I have type  `rpm -qa` and shows there is 2 kernel, tried to boot to old kernel and compile the LiS but didn't help.

I have break down my question as below:

1. How to check if the kernel libraries are matching with the kernel version ?
   idea: the dlevel, kernel, gcc, glib, glibc ...
2. It there a general steps in trouble shoot build issues, like a check list? So you can tick it one by one. The LiS installation did provide several libraries minimum level requirement, I am sure that i meet with them all, right now i suspect that i am over patch.
3. Can i just go down the file version ? so i just have every library just meet the requirement? and 100% compatible.

## Progress on Day 2

with some tips from @schaiba, i have researched how to do logging in the compile process.

while after break into the build package, trace into build strconf in a second folder, added     --verbose to the cc compiling, got the following message:
  ignore conflicting library  `/usr/lib64/libc.so` , it is a small file, so i try to open it wwith vi, thus discover it is a text file instead, for which a statement like `OUTPUT FORMAT (elf32-i386)`, which is obviously incorrect to me, since lib64 should be x86_64 instead.
  Then, I have determine to check the where do the libc.so comes from,  by:

```
rpm -qf libc.so
```

from which is discover it is in glibc-devel-...., i have get a red hat 6.4 repository, doing

```
yum update glibc-devel
```

then, the naughty libc.so became `OUTPUT FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)` and that strconf module compile. and i got the build complete.

but then, i got any other problems now. I still got the ignore conflict libc.so warning, and the LiS I build is actually used by another application, and that one seems to have some problems.

any suggestions ?

For another study around internet, that the LiS package is something native to 32-bit, thus i guess it may have part of the code require to be compile under 32-bit, Therefore arise 2 new question,

1. How can you modified a build file so that it can use two version of same libraries ?
2. Is there a way to let 2 version of devel co-exist on a linux system ? and more precise,
   2 version of /usr/lib64/libc.so

Comment: I hope you realize that without the exact errors you encountered nobody can help you troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: the error message is: fatal error ld - lc failure /lib/(kernelversion)/misc/ .o missing

Comment: Redirect stderr and stdin to some file and use a pastebin, then paste the link. Like 'gcc -options file.c > logfile.txt 2>&1'

Comment: by the way, this is the official link IBM provide [link](ftp://ftp.uk.metaswitch.com/pub/LiS/) which is a must for their CommServer

Answer (score 0):

It's a shot in the dark, but since LiS looks like it involves a kernel module (http://www.gcom.com/home/linux/lis/index.html), you probably need the kernel development package.

So try running this as root:

```
yum -y install kernel-devel kernel-headers
```

Will it build now?

Comment: i did it some other way, pretty much same direction as you have suggest, and it seems to works, at least 80%

Comment: yeah, i agree that it is **shot in the dark**. since the version i am using is [2.19](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21247997) ...... that is mad